# PDFBox's capacity to create maximum size merged pdf in Docker environment

Tags: docker, containers, pdfbox, pdfmerger

I am trying to merge 1000+ PDFs into single PDF using pdfbox mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting memUsageSetting), application is deployed in Docker environment. I'm planning to create merged PDF size of 4 GB. Currently heap size is set to 6 GB and container size is set to 6 GB. But application is breaking.

Could you please help me to understand if I need to check and adjust any other parameters?

Thank you!!

I have tried to adjust heap size and container size, but it did not help me.

Comment: Do you mean PDFBox standalone  pdfbox-app-2.0.27.jar ? How do you run docker command ? It's one time job or  will run a lot of time ?Any error message ?